# Ad b2c custom policies - msverify otp sms message localization

Tags: iphone, azure-ad-b2c, autofill, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, totp

In AD B2C Custom policies, is there anyway to translate the msverify otp sms message that send to user mobile device.

This is the content of sms message:

**"Use verification code [ some code ] for [ b2c tenant ] authentication"**

I need to set a different content for this message, as in german my IOS device can not recognize the otp code then auto-fill code does not work.

This is TechnicalProfile in custom policy:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="GenerateOtp">
          <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
            <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">1200</Item>
            <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
            <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
            <Item Key="ReuseSameCode">true</Item>
            <Item Key="NumRetryAttempts">5</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

I find here the localization specification from MS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids
But I can not find the translation for sms message.

Comment: It is not possible to edit the content of the Microsoft text messages. You would need to bring your own provider. This [custom SMS verification in Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-sms-displaycontrol) sample will help you integrate this. 
If there is a bug with the Microsoft texts and autofill, you should raise a support ticket.